# Click event firing on inner image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one small problem in click events. I have one div in that two image tags are there once I clicked on one image its firing also inner image.
Here is the code.
HTML code

```
<div id="mainContent">
 //some other code goes here..
 <img id="playId_1" src="img/new/startImgs/menuImgs/play-btn1.png"
style="z-index: 2; display: none; position: fixed;" />
  <img id="levelBg" src="img/new/startImgs/menuImgs/levelBg.png"
style="z-index: 1; display: none; position: fixed;">
 //some other code goes here..
</div>
```

Javascript Code here..

```
$('#playId_1').on('touchstart', function(e) {
  startGame();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('#levelBg').on('click', function (e) {
           alert("clicked");
 });
```

When I clicked the play button, its firing on levelBg event also(displaying clicked alert after executing startGame(0 method)
Please Anybody help me to resolve this

Comment: where is `#levelBg` ..?

Comment: How can you click `#playId_1` if it's hidden?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Please check now I have edited code..

Comment: @FelixKling I will add display=block when i need, its not hidden

Comment: Can't repro: http://jsfiddle.net/5dPYM/ (images are same size)

Comment: Maybe because they have a fixed position and might be overlapping each other?

Comment: There is no chance of happening event propagation/bubbling here..! It must be some sort of layout related issue, can you reproduce the issue on a fiddle... ?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes its happening in your fiddle BUT Im running in android devices when I click play button event is firing on both images

Comment: So can't you replace touchstart with click? The propagation stops, but for the touchstart event.. and then you have a click on the other image.

Comment: @JFK I tried changing positions to absolute then also same problem.

Comment: @LGT Yes solved sir.. Thanks for identifying touchstart instead of click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **touchstart** to **click** or vice vesa.